# grab the lat and lng

Tags: android

So i found this script to get the best location and have added it to a app. When i call for the location it just gives a random number after the package name (com.android.package.currentactivity$1@randomcode)

```
MyLocation myLocation = new MyLocation();
private void locationClick() {
    myLocation.getLocation(this, locationResult));
}

public LocationResult locationResult = new LocationResult(){
    @Override
    public void gotLocation(final Location location){
        //Got the location!
        });
    }
};
```

and the MyLocation.java

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyLocation {
    Timer timer1;
    LocationManager lm;
    LocationResult locationResult;
    boolean gps_enabled=false;
    boolean network_enabled=false;

    public boolean getLocation(Context context, LocationResult result)
    {
        //I use LocationResult callback class to pass location value from MyLocation to user code.
        locationResult=result;
        if(lm==null)
            lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //exceptions will be thrown if provider is not permitted.
        try{gps_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}
        try{network_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}

        //don't start listeners if no provider is enabled
        if(!gps_enabled && !network_enabled)
            return false;

        if(gps_enabled)
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerGps);
        if(network_enabled)
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerNetwork);
        timer1=new Timer();
        timer1.schedule(new GetLastLocation(), 20000);
        return true;
    }

    LocationListener locationListenerGps = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            timer1.cancel();
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    };

    LocationListener locationListenerNetwork = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            timer1.cancel();
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    };

    class GetLastLocation extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
             lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
             lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);

             Location net_loc=null, gps_loc=null;
             if(gps_enabled)
                 gps_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
             if(network_enabled)
                 net_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

             //if there are both values use the latest one
             if(gps_loc!=null && net_loc!=null){
                 if(gps_loc.getTime()>net_loc.getTime())
                     locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
                 else
                     locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
                 return;
             }

             if(gps_loc!=null){
                 locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
                 return;
             }
             if(net_loc!=null){
                 locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
                 return;
             }
             locationResult.gotLocation(null);
        }
    }

    public static abstract class LocationResult{
        public abstract void gotLocation(Location location);
    }
}
```

What im trying to get is the lat and lng so i can use is in my activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to be more explicit on where do you get that string, so we can help you pinpoint the issue, but that string represent your Activity instance as a String.

> public String toString ()
>   Since: API Level 1
>
> Returns a string containing a concise, human-readable description of this object. Subclasses are encouraged to override this method and provide an implementation that takes into account the object's type and data. The default implementation is equivalent to the following expression:
>
> ```
>  getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```
>
> See Writing a useful toString method if you intend implementing your own toString method.
>   Returns a printable representation of this object.

Edit: It's not your activity, but an inner class inside it (this is told by the $1 part). Perhaps the MyLocation instance?

Comment: so you see MyLocation.java and i am calling a json array to get some remote info from MySQL DB. in the URL it is posting the lat and long and the server is taking that info and spitting back the resaults. Currently I have a Toast pop up as follows `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"" + locationResult + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` In hopes i can get is to show the lat and long.

Comment: i have also tried changing the following with out success `private void findCurrentLocation() {
        myLocation.getLocation(this, locationResult);
    }

    public LocationResult locationResult = new LocationResult() {

        
        public void gotLocation(Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (location != null) {
                String strloc  = location.getLatitude() + ","
                        + location.getLongitude();
            }
        }
    };`

Comment: Please explain why you downvoted my answer. Where did I mention any sort of exception?

Comment: That's the problem. There is no `LocationResult#toString()` method overriding the default `Object#toString()`. You need to define a toString() method on LocationResult.

Comment: @Casp you didn't. But you tried to explain the "odd" string by the lack of permissions. Thus, I explained you in a comment to your answer, with a link to the documentation, that the lack of permissions is handled differently. That's it. I don't know what else did you add after that, but it does not seem to address the specific issue either.

Comment: ok now i am confused I had added `String strloc  = location.getLatitude() + ","
                        + location.getLongitude();` by someone else's advise. What should i be added to make this show the lat and lng in the toast pop?

Comment: so if i move the toast into the LocationResult it is showing the right info.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one or both of these to your manifest.xml:

```
    <uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

This is the bulk of my location code. Use it. It works.:

```
    /**************************************************************************
 * helper functions for starting/stopping monitoring of Location changes below
 **************************************************************************/

public void startListening() {

    if (networkLocationListener == null && gpsLocationListener == null) {
        // make new listeners
        networkLocationListener = new BegetLocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        gpsLocationListener = new BegetLocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // request very rapid updates initially. after first update, we'll put them back down to a much lower frequency
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 60000, 200, networkLocationListener);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 60000, 200, gpsLocationListener);
    }

    Location networkLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    if (networkLocation != null) {
        appModel.setLocation(networkLocation);
    }
    updateDistances(appModel.getLocation());
}

private void stopListening() {

    if (networkLocationListener != null)
        locationManager.removeUpdates(networkLocationListener);
    if (gpsLocationListener != null)
        locationManager.removeUpdates(gpsLocationListener);

    gpsLocationListener = null;
    networkLocationListener = null;
}

private void handleListenerDisabled(BegetLocationListener listener) {

    if (!appModel.getFlags().hasLocationMessageBeenDisplayed()) {
        if (networkLocationListener.locationStatusKnown && gpsLocationListener.locationStatusKnown) {
            if (networkLocationListener.locationIsEnabled && !gpsLocationListener.locationIsEnabled) {
                showAlert(YES_NETWORK_NO_GPS_MSG, BaseActivity.DIALOG_LOCATION);
                appModel.getFlags().setLocationMessageDisplayed(true);
            } else {
                showAlert(NO_NETWORK_NO_GPS_MSG, BaseActivity.DIALOG_LOCATION);
                appModel.getFlags().setLocationMessageDisplayed(true);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void handleLocationChanged(Location location) {

    if (location == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (isBetterLocation(location, appModel.getLocation())) {
        appModel.setLocation(location);
        stopListening();
    }
}

private class BegetLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    private String provider = "";
    private boolean locationIsEnabled = true;
    private boolean locationStatusKnown = true;

    public BegetLocationListener(String provider) {
        this.provider = provider;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
        handleLocationChanged(location);
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        startListening();
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        locationStatusKnown = true;
        locationIsEnabled = false;
        handleListenerDisabled(this);
    }
}
```

Obviously you'll want to remove the `appModel` stuff and the custom dialog stuff.

Comment: That is not how android handles security exceptions: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html

Comment: Wasn't finished. I didn't mention exceptions. I think you misclicked.

Comment: I did not "misclick". If you want to be first answering, regardless of the quality of the answer, then you will be exposed to downvotes.